# Where does Zend framework keep the default certificate store?

Tags: php, ssl, zend-framework, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have two environments, a development one and production one which mirrors the development environment.

On the development environment, I'm trying to connect to a ssl server using the zend framework and I got the following meaningless error message;

```
Unable to Connect to ssl://test.server.com:443. Error #0:
```

Using tcpdump, I found the error was due to an Unknown CA.

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Http/Client.php';
$uri = 'https://test.server.com';
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri);
$client->setHeaders(Zend_Http_Client::CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json');
$response = $client->setRawData($json)->setEncType('application/json')->request('PUT');
```

I have not specified an `sslcapath`, however my production system works fine without it. When I -do- set the `sslcapath`,

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri, array(
            'sslcapath' => '/etc/ssl/certs'
        ));
```

I still get the error.
So I think that Zend is using a certificate store somewhere (or I am setting the `sslcapath` incorrectly), and I would like to check if the CA is in the certificate store on the development environment.

My CA is in `/etc/ssl/certs` on both systems.

Is there anything else which would explain why it works on the production system, but not the development, despite being the same?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code given, you have not define the `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter`. Then the configuration will be different depends on which adapter do you choose.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html

Example using socket:

```
$config = array(
    'adapter'  => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket',
    'sslcert'  => '/etc/ssl/certs'
);

// Instantiate a client object
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri, $config);
$client->setHeaders(Zend_Http_Client::CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json');
$response = $client->setRawData($json)->setEncType('application/json')->request('PUT');
```

You can use another adapter based on your need or which adapter you like.

Comment: `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket` is the default so wouldn't that make my code identical to what you have written?
Also when I explicitly set the `/etc/ssl/certs` path, it still doesn't recognise my certificate.